# Google Analytics funnel - Virtual Pageview 100% backfill - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: google-analytics

My first post. I'm having big problems with a Goal Funnel in Google Analytics.

We've set up a funnel to track registration from our main company site to user registration which is handled on a third-party site (using a virtual pageview to track the user's 'click' to continue to the registration).

We're clearly doing something wrong however as the funnel seems to have a conversion rate of 100% for several steps. From the many tutorials and posts I've read it looks like there could be something wrong in our syntax and GA is seeing at least two pages as the same then backfilling the funnel to give this incorrect 100%.

Problem is - after many tweaks - we still can't seem to find quite what this error is. I'm also not entirely sure if we should be using 'begins with' or 'regular expression' for the funnel and if that the correct application of one of those would nip this data issue in the bud instantly.

Underneath is the configuration and then the data it's showing us in GA.

Thanks for any help on this!

p.s. Since we're using tag manager, I also wasn't sure if this could this be something in our firing rules but since the first conversion step in the funnel looks ok I guess that rules this out and points straight to the funnel??

p.p.s. Sorry, since I normally just read, I don't have permission to embed images.

[The goal flow]

[IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/pmwk8.png[/IMG]

[The funnel setup]

[IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/23lkqqt.png[/IMG]

Comment: Being that your both your Registration Page and Create an Account have 371 pageviews , I would assume that maybe your virtual pageview is being sent onload of the registration and not on click of the link or button that directs the user to the third party site.

Comment: Thanks alot Blexy, I'd read some of your other posts on Google Analytics whilst researching this. 

We've looked at that but it seems to be ok, the firing rule's set up with the following conditions:

{{event}} equals gtm.linkClick
{{element url}} equals thirdpartydomain.com/register

Is there something else we could be missing in the syntax or the way we've set this up?

Comment: Have exhausted everything I can think of for fixing this, would be grateful if anyone has any other suggestions of things I should look at or double-check? I know I'm doing something wrong - just not sure what - yet!! Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the website with us?

Comment: Hi Blexy, thanks again - the url is http://edinburgh.gov.uk, we're trying to track registration through the 'Register' button at the top right on the homepage so the funnel is: https://www.edinburgh.gov.uk/ > https://www.edinburgh.gov.uk/registration > Then the 'Register for your online account' button on this landing page triggers a virtualpageview since we don't control the third party domain.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual pageview you have in the second image in step 2, is: virtual/registration. The virtual pageview that is firing off when I click on Register for online account is: /virtual/cas-registration#https://signin.mygovscot.org/home/?sp=register/CLK. So you'll want to update step 2 to: /virtual/cas-registration(.*) - I believe you can use regular expressions in goal funnel steps.

Comment: Thanks Blexy, sorry, that was an earlier version screen grab but we have updated witth your suggestion and are holding our breath for this one! Will let you know how it turns out. Cheers again.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion on this though @Blexy ! It seemed promising but on checking again unfortunately it's still showing 100% throughput. I think I'm going to teach myself regex based swear words!

http://i57.tinypic.com/2s93k3o.png

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd have to append #https://signin.mygovscot.org/home/?sp=register/CLK to the virtual pageview? If you can leave that off of the virtual pageview, and just use /virtual/cas-registration, I think that will solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks Blexy, no reason other than wanting to make sure it was the right element. This may be the only part we haven't toyed with so far, so fingers crossed... will let you know either way. Thanks again, really great of you to offer these suggestions, cheers!

Comment: Alas, this one doesn't seem to have worked either (screenshot of yesterday below). Thanks for the help and suggestions! I'll post again if we find a solution though...cheers! http://i58.tinypic.com/1zyabes.png